# How to change color for mat-divider?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

Is it possible to change `mat-divider` color?
I tried the following, it didn't work

**component.html**

```html
<mat-divider class="material-devider"></mat-divider>
```

**component.scss**

```css
.material-devider {
    color: red
}
```

Comment: It's possible, and that's how you would do it. You likely have another rule overriding that with higher specificity. Try inspecting it with the F12 debugger.

Comment: You can use the !important keyword here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can.

You need to overrule `.mat-divider` class styling in your own written CSS and change the `border-top-color` property.

```css
.mat-divider {
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

is the default styling by Angular Material.

```css
.mat-divider {
    border-top-color: red;
}
```

This should be enough to change it (if your CSS gets rendered later than Material's). Otherwise adding increased specificity to your CSS class will help (f.e.`.mat-divider.mat-divider`).

[StackBlitz example for this case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qnx3sk?file=src/app/divider-overview-example.css).

Answer (score 2):

To change the color mat-divider simply change the border-top-color property of .mat-divider class.

```
.mat-divider {
  border-top-color: red;
}
```

https://www.angularjswiki.com/angular/angular-material-divider-mat-divider-example/#mat-divider-color

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
  <mat-divider class="mat-divider" [vertical]="true"></mat-divider>
```

Then the change is with the `border-right-color`:

```
.mat-divider {
    border-right-color: red;  
}
```